# NHibernate getting one element per category with single query

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate

I have News Class as follows:

```
    public class News
    {
        public virtual int Id { set; get; }
        public virtual string Title { get; set; }
        public virtual Category Category { set; get; }
        public virtual DateTime DateCreated { set; get;} 
    }
```

and There is category class;

```
public class Category
{
    public virtual int Id { set; get; }
    public virtual string Name { set; get;}
}
```

News table is populated with data.

What I need is to get one News per category ordered by `DateCreated`. OK So I want latest news from the category, but I want all the news for all categories.

OK I can get all categories and get last News per Category, I m curious if there is an efficient way to do this?

any ideas?

What would be the proper syntax also?

Comment: You may want to start with this article http://rickosborne.org/blog/2008/01/sql-getting-top-n-rows-for-a-grouped-query/ After you figure out what exact sql query you need I would go about constructing the NHibernate query.  If you figure out the sql query you need I would post it here as well.  You may get better responses if you say I need to convert this sql query to an Nhibernate query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, the cleanest way to do it is adding an inverse collection to the Category class (this is technically free, let me know if you need help with the mapping):

```
public virtual ICollection<News> NewsItems { get; set; }
```

And then it's a simple LINQ query:

```
var results = from category in session.Query<Category>()
              select new
                     {
                         category,
                         LatestNews = category.NewsItems
                           OrderByDescending(x => x.DateCreated).FirstOrDefault()
                     };
```